# conda.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1

Tags: linux, anaconda3

Unable to install Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64 in my RHEL machine; Getting the error -> conda.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted.

Anaconda or Miniconda version:  Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64
Operating System:"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"

**Steps to Reproduce**

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ./Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh

I've followed the resolution steps mentioned in Github #11493, and #11154 by @davidlowryduda, @Pastthesun, but that doesn't fix my issue.  Have posted the issue in Github as #11587.

I tried with older version of Anaconda --> Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64 and Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64. Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64 did not give the same issue related to libz.so.1, but gave another error. But I had a smooth installation with Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem may be your `/tmp` is set to `noexec` in `/etc/fstab`. Verify with `grep tmp /etc/fstab`.

Run the installer with `TMPDIR` set to a directory you have write permissions to, on a file system with executable permission. i.e.:

```sh
mkdir /users/$USER/tmpconda
TMPDIR=/users/$USER/tmpconda bash Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Solution was found at [Anaconda Issues 11587](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11587)

A quick test of executability on a file system:

```
$ touch foo && chmod +x foo && ./foo
-bash: ./foo: Permission denied
```

`noexec` will cause "Permission denied" even if `x` is set on the file.

Comment: Ok; I didn't get a chance to try out the TMPDIR option;  but since this is reported as having worked for many, marking this issue as closed.  Thanks all for the response  @zerocog, I accept your response as the answer !

Comment: My system IT with root access has been installing the Anaconda with the TMPDIR set to an exec capable directory. Therefore, it is working outside the the user local install.

Comment: This worked for me. Note that you should not name the directory "TMPDIR" or it will collide with the `TMPDIR` environment variable.

Comment: Most will not have the problem, and is only a problem for those that have a system environment locked down to not allow exec in the /tmp dir. Yes, you are changing the path of TMPDIR env to intentionally go to a place that will process exec. You do not need to permanently change the PATH, just for the install.

Comment: You can also remount `/tmp` with executable permissions with `sudo mount /tmp -o remount,exec` and if write permissions are also necessary, use `sudo mount /tmp -o remount,rw` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in Debian 10 and fixed the issue by exporting a writeable path to TMP environment variable.

Reference:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11154

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like this:
-- run the command >>>

```
mount |grep tmp
```

check a tmp partition that does not contain the attribute: noexec
and that contains the attribute: rw

in my case:

```
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs
(rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=3775584k,nr_inodes=943896,mode=755)
```

run in terminal:

```
export TMP='path/to/tmp'& export TMPDIR='path/to/tmp'& bash Anaconda_install_file.sh
```